# regular expression for matching correct string

Tags: regex

i have a string:

```
Recent overs</b> <tt>. . . . . . <b>|</b> 3 . . 1b 4 .<b>|</b> 1 1 1 . . 4 <b>|</b> . . . 4 . .</tt></p>
```

It is all in a single line, so how would I extract only the information about the balls, ie 
output should be `. . . . . . 3 . . 1b 4 . 1 1 1 . . 4 . . . 4 . .`

The closest i got was with `[^(Recent overs|<b>|<tt>|</b>|</tt>|</p>)]+`, but it matches the 1 and not 1b.

Comment: Balls? What balls? What does that have to do with your question?

Comment: What Regex engine or language do you use? Also, within character class the alternation have no meaning...

Comment: Sample in ruby: `x = 'Recent overs</b> <tt>. . . . . . <b>|</b> 3 . . 1b 4 .<b>|</b> 1 1 1 . . 4 <b>|</b> . . . 4 . .</tt></p>'; result = x.gsub(/<[^>]+>/, '').gsub('|', '').match(/\..*\./)[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the brackets `[]` are used for creating what is called a "character class" - this is meant to represent a single character.  Your code effectively says don't match these characters: `(Recntovrsbp|<>/`

You'd be better off using a regex to remove the unwanted strings, then it's easier to parse the result, like this:

*Javascript, because you didn't specify the language*

```
var s = "Recent overs</b> <tt>. . . . . . <b>|</b> 3 . . 1b 4 .<b>|</b> 1 1 1 . . 4 <b>|</b> . . . 4 . .</tt></p>";
s = s.replace(/(Recent overs|<[^>]+>|\|)/ig, '');
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/NZK2S/)

The resulting 's' is much easier to parse.

Answer (score 0):

Try `\s[\d\.][\w]*` to match all digit (possibly followed by word) characters or points preceeded by a space!

Comment: The first group of `.`'s doesn't have a space before it.

Comment: Also, this will match `overs` in `Recent overs`.

Comment: But in either case, each data point will be in a separate match; i.e. each `.` will be a single match, each `1` will be a single match...each match will consist of one character, except for `1b`. He seems to want them grouped together according to which tag pair they're in.

Comment: @Justin: According to the regex he provided he can live with separate matches.

Answer (score 0):

Based solely on the example you gave, you could try something like:

```
/(?<>)[a-z\d\s\.]+/g
```

Alternative, in case your regex engine doesn't support lookbehinds:

```
/>([a-z\d\s\.]+)/g     #Matches will be in the first capture group.
```

However, it's a little hard to infer the rules of what should/should not be allowed based on the small sample you gave, and your output sample doesn't make much sense to me as a data structure. It seems like you might be better off using an HTML parser for this, since [using regex to process HTML is frequently a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).